# Automatic cast to pointer without automatic cast to bool(-like) possible?

Tags: c++

Is is possible to create a class `Wrapper` such that

```
void f(void *) {}

Wrapper w;
f(w);
```

compiles, but

```
Wrapper w;
if (w) {}
```

doesn't compile? Or detect the difference at runtime?

Background: A win32 `HANDLE` is a typedef for `void *`. Win32 doesn't use `NULL` but instead `((HANDLE)(-1))` as an error value, so any code implicitly casting a `HANDLE` to bool is almost certainly testing the wrong thing. I have a class wrapping a `HANDLE`, and if possible I would like to remove this opportunity for errors when using the wrapper class.

Comment: Some return `NULL`. Some return `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/02/82639.aspx

Comment: That was worse than I expected (and I _read_ The Old New Thing). Oh well, still interested in answers despite the lack of practical use in this context.

Comment: I don't know how many posts I've reread and didn't remember anything from them before :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++11 it is possible by using *deleted functions*. For instance:

```
struct Wrapper
{
    operator void* () { }
    operator bool () = delete;
};

void foo(void*) { }

int main()
{
    Wrapper w;

    foo(w); // OK

    if (w) // ERROR!
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you are working with a compiler that does not support C++11, you can achieve the same result by declaring the `bool` conversion operator `private`:

```
struct Wrapper
{
    operator void* () { }
private:
    operator bool () { };
};
```

This works because accessibility of a function is verified only at the very last step of overload resolution.

Comment: I think you meant `foo(w);` and `if (w)` :)

Comment: @chris: you're a compiler :-) Thx

Comment: This is wonderful, but it appears that the OP is using Windows, which implies MSVC++, which is notorious for it's lack of newer C++ features. Can anyone confirm that this will work with the latest version of MSVC++?

Comment: Well, even a compiler wouldn't pick up on the first one, as we want the `operator void*`, not just the address. Does that mean I'm better than a compiler? :p

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, Nope, not as of the CTP.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: That's a good point. Well, this is a theoretical answer then. I don't think it's possible on C++03

Comment: This looks like the way to go in C++11. Either `delete` or `private` seems to combine great with `explicit operator bool` too. Any idea if it's combinable with C++03 safe-bool ideoms in some way?

Comment: @BaffeBoyois: If I'm not mistaken, the safe-bool idiom is about getting `if (w)` to compile, while you seem to be aiming at *not* making it compile. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Oops, ignore that. It's hard to think just about the simplified code posted instead of the code I have here...

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a version that works, but bear in mind that this is a *terrible* idea to have in production code:

```
struct Wrapper {
    void *_value;

    Wrapper() : _value(NULL) {

    };

    template<typename T>
    Wrapper(T *value) : _value(value) {

    };

    void *operator &() {
        return _value;
    };
};

void func(void *value) {
    printf("%p", value);
}

int main()
{
    Wrapper w = (void *) 0xFFAABB;

    if (w) // error, 'No viable conversion from 'Wrapper' to 'bool'
    {
        func(&w); // 0xffaabb
    }
}
```

You cannot pass the wrapper directly, but passing the address of the wrapper will convert it to the address of the value.

**Be very careful** if you are trying to use this with external template functions, as they may not operate correctly.